# Implementing OAuth2.0 to secure microservice architecture

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices

I have been looking for several weeks to find a way to secure my application using microservice architecture using OAuth2 and I couldn't find any helpful material.

I would appreciate if anyone of you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://github.com/OmarElGabry/microservices-spring-boot) you can find a [complete example](https://github.com/OmarElGabry/microservices-spring-boot) implementing microservices architecture,
this could help you :)

Comment: Méd, answers [should not contain just a link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be good to describe a solution, so it's available even if the link stop working. And the linked content is rarely an exact answer to its question.

Comment: Ján, you're alright, i will summarize a brief answer so it will be helpful in case the link is damaged, in the future.
thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A common option is to use 2 levels of API:

- The outside world connects to entry point APIs targeted at particular customers - eg Online Sales UI / B2B Partners
- Entry point APIs call potentially many microservices focused on domain capabilities (Product / Customer / Stock)

In terms of security:

- Entry point APIs require OAuth tokens
- They validate tokens and get claims
- They orchestrate calls to microservices
- Microservices are in a locked down virtual private cloud
- Microservices do not use OAuth security
- Microservices receive OAuth claims, perhaps via headers

In this type of setup, microservices need to be properly locked down - typically no person should be able to access them directly in Staging or PROD - though you may make exceptions in earlier stages of the pipeline for QA purposes.

Also of course your stakeholders would need to sign off on whether this is acceptable from a security viewpoint.

Some further thoughts of mine in my [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2019/03/24/api-platform-design/), though I am in the early days of applying this at scale.